# Python Create Pandas Dataframe From txt file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have file.txt like this. i want create dataframe with pandas.

```
# NISN:- 1234567
# FullName:- Joe Doe
# FirstName:- Joe
# LastName:- Doe
# School:- Klima
# E-mail:- joe@gmail.com

# NISN:- 8901234
# FullName:- Jenny Low
# FirstName:- Jenny
# LastName:- Low
# School:- Kimcil
# E-mail:- jenny@gmail.com
```

how to convert dataframe to this?

```
NISN    Fullname    FirstName   LastName    School  E-mail
1234567 Joe Doe     Joe     Doe     Klima   joe@gmail.com
8901234 Jenny Low   Jenny       Low     Kimcil  jenny@gmail.com
```

edited

---

i found sample bad line in file. how to handle this?

```
# NISN:- 123456

7
# FullName:- Joe Doe
# FirstName:- Joe
# LastName:- Doe
# School:- Klima
# E-mail:- joe@gmail.com



# NISN:- 8901234
# FullName:- Jenny Low
# FirstName:- Jenny
# LastName:- Low
# School:- Kimc

il
# E-mail:- jenny@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the lines of your file in python and store the relevant data into a `dictionary` before converting it to a `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
with open("file.txt") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        line = line.strip("# \n")        # clean up whitespace and # for lines
        if not line:                     # skip empty lines
            continue

        name, value = line.split(":- ") 
        data[name].append(value)
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(df)
      NISN   FullName FirstName LastName  School           E-mail
0  1234567    Joe Doe       Joe      Doe   Klima    joe@gmail.com
1  8901234  Jenny Low     Jenny      Low  Kimcil  jenny@gmail.com
```

Comment: hi friend, why i getting error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Most likely you have lines in your file that are not representative of your post. Certain lines that don't contain information that should be skipped are not being skipped. Are there any lines that don't contain this format `# name:- value` that are not simply blank lines? Alternatively, are you sure that there are no pairings that are missing the space e.g. `# name:-value`?

Comment: it turns out that my file is bad. I found some lines that are not properly formatted. how to find non-formatted rows and resolve them?

Comment: my problem solved with your code. thank you. you true, i found `# name:-value`

Answer (score 2):

If each group has exactly 6 rows you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `name` parameter for 2 columns, in separator `\s*` is regex for zero or more spaces after `:-`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=":-\s*", names=['a', 'b'], engine='python')
print (df)
              a                b
0        # NISN          1234567
1    # FullName          Joe Doe
2   # FirstName              Joe
3    # LastName              Doe
4      # School            Klima
5      # E-mail    joe@gmail.com
6        # NISN          8901234
7    # FullName        Jenny Low
8   # FirstName            Jenny
9    # LastName              Low
10     # School           Kimcil
11     # E-mail  jenny@gmail.com
```

Alternative for read file - used separator which not exist in data like `|` or `¥` and then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), but only by first separator by `n=1`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="|", names=['data'])
print (df)
                          data
0             # NISN:- 1234567
1         # FullName:- Joe Doe
2            # FirstName:- Joe
3             # LastName:- Doe
4             # School:- Klima
5     # E-mail:- joe@gmail.com
6             # NISN:- 8901234
7       # FullName:- Jenny Low
8          # FirstName:- Jenny
9             # LastName:- Low
10           # School:- Kimcil
11  # E-mail:- jenny@gmail.com

df = df.pop('data').str.split(':-\s', n=1, expand=True)
df.columns = ['a','b']
print (df)
              a                b
0        # NISN          1234567
1    # FullName          Joe Doe
2   # FirstName              Joe
3    # LastName              Doe
4      # School            Klima
5      # E-mail    joe@gmail.com
6        # NISN          8901234
7    # FullName        Jenny Low
8   # FirstName            Jenny
9    # LastName              Low
10     # School           Kimcil
11     # E-mail  jenny@gmail.com
```

Then use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and reshape valus of column `b` by [`numpy.ndarray.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.strip('# ')
df = pd.DataFrame(df.b.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 6), columns = df.a.iloc[:6].rename(None))
print (df)
      NISN   FullName FirstName LastName  School           E-mail
0  1234567    Joe Doe       Joe      Doe   Klima    joe@gmail.com
1  8901234  Jenny Low     Jenny      Low  Kimcil  jenny@gmail.com
```

If possible some values missing, but always `NISN` exist for each group use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with helper column for distinguish each group by compare `a` by first value `NISN` and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.strip('# ')
df['idx'] = df['a'].eq('NISN').cumsum()
df = df.pivot(index='idx', columns='a', values='b').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
a           E-mail FirstName   FullName LastName     NISN  School
0    joe@gmail.com       Joe    Joe Doe      Doe  1234567   Klima
1  jenny@gmail.com     Jenny  Jenny Low      Low  8901234  Kimcil
```

Comment: hi thank you for answer, i getting error ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 2737, saw 3. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: @Hendra - added alternative solution for read file.

Comment: it turns out that my file is bad. I found some lines that are not properly formatted. how to find non-formatted lines and resolve them?

Comment: i dont know, i cant search manually, cuz there 4500 lines. i have added sample bad lines in my post.

Comment: @Hendra - Is possible filter only lines starting by `#` like `df = df[df['a'].str.startswith('#')].copy()` before `df['a'] = df['a'].str.strip('# ')` ?

Comment: sorry my friend, can you full code in your post? I get an error when reading the file. df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=":-\s*", names=['a', 'b'], engine='python')

Comment: @Hendra - Are data confidental? Is possible share file?

Comment: hi, sorry i cant share my file. but my problem is solved. thank you @jezrael

Comment: @Hendra - Super :)